# Is there something similar to strcpy but for int value?

Tags: c

Thank you, it works ....................................................................

```
strcpy(holder[pos].key, new.key); 

holder[pos].position = new.position

strcpy(holder[pos].name, new.name);

strcpy(holder[pos].country, new.country);
```

Comment: why you can't use simple assignment?

Comment: Why do you think you need anything different from a regular assignment? Do you realize that the fact that you use `strcpy` comes from the fact that you are copying NUL-terminated arrays of bytes, and has nothing to do with structures?

Comment: The 'normal' use to copy a integer value is really simpler. Just assign as `holder[pos].key = new.key`.

Comment: It would help to see the structure definition.

Comment: What about `memcpy()`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `strcpy` or any special function for that. Strcopy is only necessary because strings aren't strictly just a data type in C, but null-terminated char arrays.

You can do it like this:

```
holder[pos].position = new.position; // Assigns the value of new.position to holder[pos].position
```

Answer (score 1):

please use

`holder[pos].position = new.position`